# How to get minimum value from an of type list generated from Linq to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm returning a list of database records;

```
Dim rsPublicChilds As System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult(Of spGetPublicObjectsResult) = Nothing

rsPublicChilds = dc.spGetPublicObject(slintLoginID, lintLanguageID, lintObjectID, lintObjectTypeID, lstrSEOURL, lstrValid)
```

I get an enumerable list of rsPublicChildObjects that I then convert to an array;

```
Dim larr_PublicChild As IEnumerable(Of spGetPublicObjectsResult) = rsPublicChilds.toArray()
```

That then gives me easy access to an array of the objects, so I can then do;

```
larr_publicchild(0).colMyValue
```

etc.etc

I'd like to get the minimum value of colMyValue (or any other property of the object that's been created for me) but I can't quite see how to get there.

thanks
Andy

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
someCollection.Min(Function(x) x.SomeProperty)
```