# VB.Net List (Of PointF) how to get minimum of y Coordinate

Tags: vb.net, list

I am new to VB.net and I am using a List of PointF in my Programm. Now I have to get the Minimum y - Ordinate. I know the source code in c++, but as I am not to this language I can't get their syntax. Can you please give me a brief example? Thank You Best regards

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get minimum value from an of type list generated from Linq to SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432000/how-to-get-minimum-value-from-an-of-type-list-generated-from-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use LINQ, it is as simple as:

```
YourListOfPointFs.Min(Function(p) p.Y)
```

If you don't use LINQ, a simple loop should get you the same thing.

Comment: Yes it does. The syntax i provided is for vb.net.

Comment: @FrederikUbben I'm pretty sure vb.net supports LINQ: [Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx)

Comment: You may need some IMPORTS statements to get access to Linq.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546156.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396